# How do I hover mouse over an element with Codeception?

Tags: php, unit-testing, hover, mouse, codeception

Hope someone can help/point me to a answer....

I am using Codeception for testing our website.  All is well, except that I can not find a way to hover over a menu element to reveal the rest of the menu.

With watir & webdriver I was able to use

> browser.div(:class->"menu-item-1").hover

I did find  `moveMouseOver`, but it does not seem to work. I've tried

```
moveMouseOver('//div/div/div/div/ul/li[2]/a')
```

and

> moveMouseOver('.menu-item-1')

Answer (score 8):

This is working for me with Codeception version 2.0.9 (to test for the appearance of Pin It buttons on image hover on a WordPress blog post):

```
$I->amOnPage( '/blog/post-1/' );
$I->moveMouseOver( '.entry-content img' );
$I->seeElement( 'a[title="Pin it!"]' );
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but wouldn't `$I->seeElement( 'a[title="Pin it!"]' );` be true regardless of the mouse over?

Comment: No, because `seeElement` checks that the element is present and visible while `seeElementInDOM` checks that it exists whether it's visible or not.

http://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver#seeElement

Comment: Fails with latest version of Selenium and Firefox, but works fine with Firefox 47.0.1 and Selenium 2.53.1.